# AspectJ - @Before, method and thread

Tags: multithreading, aop, aspectj

In AspectJ:

```
@Before("execution(method_a)")
public void method_b() {
}
@Before("execution(method_a)")
public void method_c() {
}
```

1. Does method_a and method_b have necessarily the same threadId?
2. If method_b and method_c will be run parallel, method_a is thread safe?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am really talking about AspectJ here because you asked that way, *not* about Spring AOP.

The answer is: AspectJ instruments Java byte code, but does not run in its own thread. Both advice `method_b` and `method_c` will run in the same thread as `method_a` (awful choice of names, BTW) unless you start your own threads from within advice.

As for the order in which the two advice pointing to the same joinpoint are executed, you can select it if both advice are in different aspects via `@DeclarePrecedence`. If they are within the same aspect, the order is as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html#advice-precedence).